# What's the "real" algorithm for css filter hue-rotate?

Tags: ruby, svg, webkit, hue, svg-filters

I'm currently trying to replicate the css filter "hue-rotate", which produces the same as svg feColorMatrix "hueRotate" across browsers, on the server. I looked at the spec, the firefox implementation and the webkit implementation.
I ported each algorithm to ruby, but the results are still different from what I see in my browsers.

I have put togehter a little [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/081xrgeo/1/) to see the differences for an example image.

```
<body>
<p>Original image:</p>
<div class="image"></div>
<p>Browser filtered image: (<- I need this generated on the server!</p>
<div class="image hue-90" ></div>
<p>Webkit/spec algorithm image:</p>
<div class="webkit-algorithm-result"></div>
</body>
```

And here's the plain [ruby-code](http://codepad.org/Km9TfabU) to convert the image.

The question is: What is the secret ingredient? Why is the resulting image still different?

PS:
Even though algorithms of firefox and webkit are slightly different, the result is the same.
I tried image magick and gimp which are produce equal results but are again different from browser results AND different from the assumed algorithms above.
Phantomjs has other bugs.

[Firefox Implementation](https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/390d478480f9/gfx/src/FilterSupport.cpp)

[Webkit Implementation](https://github.com/WebKit/webkit/blob/fb3c15607f80e19d7d3773e0cbcabe5bb2d6125e/Source/WebCore/platform/graphics/texmap/TextureMapperShaderProgram.cpp)

[Spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/filters.html#feColorMatrixElement)

Comment: One thing that it looks like you are not doing is converting the colours to the sRGB colour space (which is required by the spec).  Though I don't think that will explain the big difference in your images.

Comment: image magick says my source image has sRGB:
spaceparty.png PNG 120x120 120x120+0+0 8-bit sRGB 31.8KB 0.000u 0:00.009

Comment: as Robert Longson stated, I accidentally interchanged some color values. Still ruby, and even jruby was way to slow for my needs. I ended up with this c++ cmd tool https://github.com/RedRoosterMobile/huerotate-like-webkit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't you need to have the arguments in the right order?

> def calculate_hue_webkit(r,b,g,angle)

...

> result = calculate_hue_webkit(r,g,b,90)

Comment: dude, big hug to you! I need new glasses.. Now the resulting image is exactly what I was looking for!